# How to print logs for 2 classes in 2 different files in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have set logging.file=C:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/hib.log in application.properties and setting  like below in class

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ChargeMasterController.class);

    logger.info("Total time taken for  is ---------------------------" + time  + " ms");
```

Logs are getting printed fine in the path mentioned as logging.file.

Now I want to print my logs in 2 different files for 2 different classes(In same package), how can I set 2 logging.file in application.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with the configuration Spring provides. But since `spring-boot-starter-logging` uses Logback by default, you can use a Logback configuration in stead and define multiple appenders, for example:

```xml
<appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log1.log</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>log2.log</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

After that, you could use the `FILE1` appender for your first class, `FILE2` appender for your second class, and `STDOUT` for all other classes. This can be done by defining the loggers:

```xml
<logger name="com.example.pkg.ClassName1" additivity="false" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE1" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.example.pkg.ClassName2" additivity="false" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE2" />
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

As you can see, there are two loggers next to the root logger, called `com.example.pkg.ClassName1` and `com.example.pkg.ClassName2`. These should match the names of the classes that should log to separate files.

The `additivity="false"` is important to make sure that logs that go to `log1.log` or `log2.log` aren't also sent to the console since they would also match the root logger.

This configuration can be placed within a `logback.xml` file on your classpath (eg. `src/main/resources`). Alternatively, you can also configure the location by using the `logging.config` property within `application.properties`. For example:

```
logging.config=file:/path/to/logback.conf
```

Or if you want to use an arbitrary location on your classpath:

```
logging.config=classpath:my/logback.conf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I name above files please? and will these be parallel to application.properties

Comment: @DheerajMadan The names are provided in the configuration of the appenders. As you can see, both appenders use the `<file>` element. No clue what you mean with your last question though. But perhaps I should clarify that this is a replacement of the logging configuration in `application.properties`.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your response, I meant the file name where I should put above code, that is logback.xml

Comment: Ah yes indeed, create a file called `logback.xml` within your classpath (eg. `src/main/resources`). I clarified that in my answer now.